# Copyrights & Licenses: A bit lost

Tags: c#, apache, licensing, lgpl

We're getting ready to deploy a commercial application. Our software makes use of several other libraries, which have licenses ranging from the [Code Project Open License (CPOL)](http://www.codeproject.com/info/cpol10.aspx), the [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html), the [Apache License](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/license.html), and the [MIT License](http://commandline.codeplex.com/license)

We want to comply with all of these licenses, obviously, but we're a small outfit that doesn't have a legal department to help us out with these things. Currently, as all the libraries are dynamically linked, and not embedded into the executable, I think we're mostly in the clear. Our project is closed-source, and is intended to be sold, and possibly resold by those we provide it to.

In the source code that uses these libraries, we've placed the related license at the head of the file.

In our About Box, we've placed the licenses as well (Is this step necessary)

Would we also need to include a LICENSE file upon distribution of our software?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Fair enough, I was just wondering if anyone had any experience with how to display licenses, but I guess that could be worded "How to comply with X license"

Comment: If you as programmer use some code, look into it's license text and comply with it. If you have understanding problems, you can ask other developers what they think about that, but we can not answer your legal questions if you need legal help. A tip if you want to save some money: Contact the original copyright holder(s), ask what's applicable and if you're kind and respect others, I'm pretty sure you can sort this out in no time. Also if you ask here, not only drop the license names but also the concrete software because often people don't know the exact license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When talking about selling, and possibility reselling, you don't want your programmers writing your licensing.

**Hire a lawyer.**